# Check for only open port with perl

Tags: linux, perl

I need to write a script to scan ports on server and generate a report. This script should:

Read a list of IPs from a file;
Scan each IP, and write a file with the results.

I am using below script for this::

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use IO::Socket::PortState qw(check_ports);

my $hostfile = 'hosts.txt';

my %port_hash = (
        tcp => {
            22      => {},
            443     => {},
            80      => {},
            53      => {},
            30032   => {},
            13720   => {},
            13782   => {},
            }
        );

my $timeout = 5;

open HOSTS, '<', $hostfile or die "Cannot open $hostfile:$!\n";

while (my $host = <HOSTS>) {
    chomp($host);
    my $host_hr = check_ports($host,$timeout,\%port_hash);
    print "Host - $host\n";
    for my $port (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$host_hr->{tcp}}) {
        my $yesno = $host_hr->{tcp}{$port}{open} ? "yes" : "no";
        print "$port - $yesno\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close HOSTS;
```

Now I have 1 thing to do with is::

**Scan for all open ports.**

Currently it is scanning ports **%port_hash** but I need to scan all the ports and list ports which are open. How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to write a perl Script to scan open ports on servers and create a report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724801/need-to-write-a-perl-script-to-scan-open-ports-on-servers-and-create-a-report)

Comment: @sudo_O That question was closed because it wasn't a real question. This looks better, it has code to discuss.

Comment: As mentioned in your other question, why aren't you using `nmap`?

Comment: @barmar - I'm guessing because this is a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fill up %porthash with all the ports:

```
my %port_hash = ( tcp => {} );
for my $port (1 .. 65535) {
  $port_hash{'tcp'}{$port} = {};
}
```

Then you can call `check_ports` with this %port_hash.

Comment: I have write above code after my $hostfile = 'hosts.txt'; line and it shows below errors::

"my" variable $hostfile masks earlier declaration in same scope at scanner.pl line 21.
"my" variable $hostfile masks earlier declaration in same statement at scanner.pl line 21.
syntax error at scanner.pl line 16, near "%port_hash{"
Can't use global $! in "my" at scanner.pl line 21, near "$hostfile:$!"
Execution of scanner.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses but it is still returning below results:

Host - 127.0.0.1
Open ports are:

Host - 94.200.xx.xx0
Open ports are:

means it is returning all blank

Comment: I typoed the `port_hash` variable name, does that fix it?

Comment: yes, Thanks @barmer It works now.

can you please suggest my how to put output in a file?

Comment: Use output redirection in the shell: `scriptname > file`

Comment: Port scanning took time for all 65535 ports. is is still scanning for ports. :(